# How to infer the type of an array that is the property of an object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to initialize a class instances property with a function. I want the instances properties type to be restricted to `Array<T>`. I tried to unpack `T` by using typescripts *infer*.

```js
class X {
    arr: Array<number>
}

type Unpacked<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : never

function setDefault<T, K extends keyof T>(object: T, key: K, value: Unpacked<T[K]>): void {
    object[key] = [value]
}

setDefault(new X(), 'arr', 1);
```

Sadly the assignment `object[key] = [value]` gives me the compiler error:
`TS2322: Type 'Unpacked<T[K]>[]' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.`

I feel like this is an easy task but I just cannot get my head around why this is not working.

Comment: The error vanishes if you replace `T` inside `setDefault` with `X`. I'm not entirely sure, but a completely generic `T` combined with `keyof T` may not be possible here, since you assume that `T[K]` *can be unpacked*. What if I were to add a string property to class `X`? Maybe you need to restrict `K` to the keys for which unpacking is possible or something like that... I'd have a look at https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials, maybe there is something helpful